# Is the function still virtual in derived class if it inherit from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a question about the pure virtual functions in c++:

```
// shape.h
class Shape
{
public:
   virtual void SetName() = 0;  
};

// round.h
#include "shape.h"
class Round: public Shape
{
   void SetName();
};
```

`class Round` inherits `class Shape`, `SetName` in base class `Shape` is virtual, and then in derived class `Round` define the `SetName` without `virtual` keyword, is this `SetName` function inherited from base class `Shape` and it is still virtual?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm looking for a suitable duplicate.

Comment: Yes. `virtual` may be repeated for clarity purposes and `override` appended for even more.